# Nvidia 980ti Drivers for v19.04

Tags: gpu-driver

I have tried to find instructions on how to get my Nvidia 980ti to work with my Ubuntu install. I am running 19.04. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: The 980 Ti is supported by the NVidia blob 430.14: https://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable the wayland support in gdm3

sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

find the following line

#WaylandEnable=false

change to

WaylandEnable=false

reboot computer

then run the autoinstall command

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

or

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-(driver number to install)